# How to substitute variables correctly within a function

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm having difficulty getting the correct variable substitution to work within this function, especially the use of `echo "$(...)` string.

```
outputOFF ()
{
   host='mydevreporting.com'
   _pw='123456foobar'
   _dt=$(date +'%m-%d-%y')
   exp="SELECT * FROM metrics.account_use where account='foo' and profile='bar' order by date desc;";
   echo "$(grep real < <({ time mysql -u admin -p${_pw} -h ${host} -N -e "$exp"} 2>&1)):localhost:${_dt}"
   #echo "$(grep real < <(\{ time mysql -u admin -p${_pw} -h ${host} -N -e "$exp"\} 2>&1)):localhost:${_dt}"
}
```

From the command line, it will work:

```
echo "$(grep real < <({ time mysql -u admin -p123456foobar -h mydevreporting.com -N -e "SELECT * FROM metrics.account_use where account='foo' and profile='bar' order by date desc;"; } 2>&1)):localhost:$(date +'%m-%d-%y')"
```

As I'm seeing error messages:

```
./tst.sh: command substitution: line 40: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./tst.sh: command substitution: line 40: `{ time mysql -u admin -p${_pw} -h ${host} -N -e "$exp"} 2>&1)'
```

As you can see the `echo "$(...)` is inside this function `outputOFF()`.

I've also tried escaping the braces `\{, \}`, which allows the variables to substitute, but somehow that command isn't working as it should.
`echo "$(grep real < <(\{ time mysql -u admin -p${_pw} -h ${host} -N -e "$exp"\} 2>&1)):localhost:${_dt}"`

So, i'm stuck.

Comment: The first quote in `"$exp"` ends the string. Thus the content of $exp is exposed to shell evaluation. Happily for you, some grouping prevents that. But I would not trust that construct. A `time mysql ... | grep real` would be easier to write and understand.

Comment: @ULick, command substitution can contain quotes (and pretty much has to, exactly to quote the variables within it.), so no, the quotes around `"$exp`" don't end the quoting. That whole construct still does look a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: If you have a better, simpler and readable construct, I would love to see it. Thank you.

Comment: @ilkkachu Didn't want to explore, why exactly it is working.  Tried to untangle it a bit. See below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `;` in the `{...}` group expression, after `"$exp"` (see this [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) for why). Here is the corrected version:

```
echo "$(grep real < <({ time mysql -u admin -p${_pw} -h ${host} -N -e "$exp"; } 2>&1)):localhost:${_dt}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Less braces makes it more readable, at least for me.

```
result=$( { time mysql -u admin -p${_pw} -h ${host} -N -e "$exp"; } 2>&1 | grep real  ); 
echo "${result}:localhost:${_dt}"
```

`time` is reporting on stderr. Thus the `{}` are neceessary to capture the output.

Or discarding the result, and only capture the result of time.

```
result=$( { time mysql -u admin -p${_pw} -h ${host} -N -e "$exp" >/dev/null; }  2>&1 )
echo ${result}":localhost:${_dt}"
```

The unquoted `${result}` is printed without the newlines. Thus you can keep all information from `time` with the additional timestamp.